# MediaPlayer problem: all songs playing at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, windows-media-player

So I'm trying to play a certain mix of songs that user chooses. I'm making an array of strings that are filenames that should be played in MediaPlayer. The problem is that all of the songs play at the same time. I've tried everything but still don't know how to make sure player waits for a song to end before it starts another one.

Here's what I've tried:

```
public void play(View v){

        if(player==null)
        {
            while(true) {
                if(i==brojac) break; //checking if the arraylist has ended
                if(player.isPlaying()==false) {
                    i++;
                    String s = lista.get(i).toString();
                    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, (this.getResources().getIdentifier(s, "raw", this.getPackageName())));
                    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            stopPlayer();
                        }
                    });
                    player.start();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

```
private void stopPlayer()
    {
        if(player!=null)
        {
            player.release();
            player=null;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

With the answer below everything works,but the player is having noticable gap. I've solved it with setNextPlayer() function, but the app crashes due to recreating the player while it is playing.

```
void playSong(int currentSong) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, currentSong);
        player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,this.getResources().getIdentifier(lista.get(i+1).toString(),"raw",getPackageName()));
        player.setNextMediaPlayer(player1);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.release();
                i++;
                if(i==brojac) return;
                player1.start();
                playSong(MainActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(lista.get(i).toString(),"raw",getPackageName()));
            }
        });
        if(i==0) {
            player.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
        for (Field field : fields)
            songs.add(getResources().getIdentifier(field.getName(), "raw", getPackageName()));
        playSong(songs.get(currentIndex));

    }


    void playSong(int currentSong) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, currentSong);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(completeListener);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completeListener = mp -> {
        mp.release();
        currentIndex++;
        playSong(songs.get(currentIndex));
    };
```

---

**Explication :**

The below code, will get all the audio files from `raw` folder and store them in the `ArrayList` called songs :

```
 Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
 for (Field field : fields)
            songs.add(getResources().getIdentifier(field.getName(), "raw", getPackageName()));
```

To play song :

```
void playSong(int currentSong) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, currentSong);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(completeListener);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

the `OnCompletionListener` listener, when the song ends, you need to increment the `currentIndex` so the `songs.get(currentIndex)` will give you the next song

```
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completeListener = mp -> {
        mp.release();
        currentIndex++;
        playSong(songs.get(currentIndex));
    };
```

Comment: yes thanks a lot, that solved my problem of all songs playing at the same time. But there is a really noticable gap between player stopping and starting once again to play another song,is there a way to do this more efficiently..?

Comment: Hi, I haven't faced this kind of issue, in fact to test the code, I used short ringtones, make sure the gap is not coming from the song itself, otherwise if you don't mind share wih me your songs names, I will download them and test the code again

Comment: I've personally made my short clips that are actually chords played on guitar in a certain rythm,and i've cut them in audacity so there is sure no delay. I've managed to get rid of that delay with using setNextMediaPlayer(player1) and player1=MediaPlayer.create(next song), then player1.start() in the OnComplition method, but because of recursion when in goes back to the playSong,player1 is playing and in the same time I'm recreating it,and it crashes,but there is no gap... I don't know how to solve that,I will make an edit to show you the code